# Why my Pepper robot is not able to be activated by trigger sentences?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I'm trying to start behaviours that actually works on Pepper by using **trigger sentences**. I'm able to start them by using *Launch Trigger Conditions* and *Run buttons* (of course). The Autonomous Life is on but Pepper seems not to listen to me, even though it hears and localizes sounds (its eyes are not blue). I applied the procedure found at this link: https://www.brainaryinteractive.com/news/2017/8/14/nao-tipsvol-3-how-to-packageand-installapplications-with-trigger-sentences

Comment: Does the robot look around, and catches your gaze? Does the robot start to listen? Using Choregraphe's "Robot Applications" widget, could you tell which activities are running?

Comment: Yes, he catches me and answers to "basic channel" questions. Anyway, it does not understand my trigger sentence: he understands different word with low probability, so I think that there's some error which does not send my trigger sentence to its system, since it does not expect that sentence

Comment: What is your trigger sentence? Is it in the right language? What does the robot understand?

Comment: Everything is set in Italian (robot settings, project properties...) and my trigger sentence is "ospedale" (hospital). Anyway I tried with other words/sentences, too. The robot understands different words/sentences, that clearly belong to basic channel dialogs.

Comment: It is not impossible there is a bug. To investigate it, could you tell me whether it works in English? Could show us all the trigger sentences you have put in the project properties?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a dialog and using the command ^switchfocus(applicationID/behavior_1). Anyway, I thank you for the help and the support.

Answer (score 0):

With NAOqi 2.5, according to this piece of documentation about [basic conversation abilities](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/nao/basic_channel_conversation_nao.html), you must first subscribe and install the [Basic Channel](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/nao_user_guide/install_basic_channel.html).

If this does not works for some reason,
you can still create a dialog, set it public,
and call `^switchfocus(applicationID/behavior_1)` from there.